# Bluetooth Discovery Doesn't Work Properly in ANDROID

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm trying to make an app which finds the Bluetooth devices, then connects them and does some issues with these devices. I have my own java class which I called it `Device` that take to Strings: `name` and `address`. Also, I have my own adapter which I called `DeviceAdapter` which takes two arguments: `context` and `list<Device>`. What I would like to do is that I take the name and the address of the device which my app finds after discovery operation and put these values into my class. Then I show these values by list view which has a custom layout that I designed for device name and address using my own adapter. In the main activity, I have 3 buttons:

1. Enable (which enables the Bluetooth)
2. List Bonded Devices (I haven't been able to pair any device yet.)
3. Find Devices (which implements the discovery operation and finds the Bluetooth devices near my app.)

I have problems with the third one. The problem is, the `ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED` and `ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` works properly as I can check the current action with `if` statement and show Toasts. When it comes to `ACTION_FOUND` I'm trying to get the name and the address of the device. I put some breakpoints which ensure that program goes inside the `ACTION_FOUND` part. Also, I can see that `device.getName()` and `device.getAddress()` returns something different than null. But after taking the values, the program crashes because of the reason that I don't know.

I couldn't find any situation like that so I couldn't find any answer. I tried everything I can but no solution. Here is the code:

### EDITED

Because I make the variables in my `Device.java` public, the program crashes. But now, It doesn't enter the Broadcast Receiver.

### FoundDevicesActivity

```
public class FoundDevicesActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
ListView foundedDevicesListView;
DeviceAdapter deviceAdapter;
List<Device> foundedDevicesList;
ProgressBar pb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_found_devices);

    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    foundedDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.foundDevicesListview);
    pb = new ProgressBar(FoundDevicesActivity.this);
    pb.setEnabled(false);

    if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

    filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            pb.setIndeterminate(true);
            Toast.makeText(FoundDevicesActivity.this, "Discovery is started !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(FoundDevicesActivity.this, "Discovery is done successfully !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Device dvc = new Device();
            if (device.getName().equals(null)) {
                dvc.name = "UNDEFINED NAME";
            } else {
                dvc.name = device.getName();
            }

            if (device.getAddress().equals(null)) {
                dvc.address = "UNDEFINED ADDRESS";
            } else {
                dvc.address = device.getAddress();
            }
            foundedDevicesList.add(dvc);
            deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(FoundDevicesActivity.this, foundedDevicesList);
            foundedDevicesListView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
            deviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

### Device.java

```
public class Device {
    public String name;
    public String address;
```

}

### DeviceAdapter.java

```
public class DeviceAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context ctx;
List<Device> DeviceList;

public DeviceAdapter(Context context, List<Device> DvcList) {
    ctx = context;
    DeviceList = DvcList;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return DeviceList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return DeviceList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Device Dvc = DeviceList.get(position);
    final View gorunum = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.devices_listview_layout, null);
    TextView deviceAddress = (TextView) gorunum.findViewById(R.id.deviceAddress);
    deviceAddress.setText(Dvc.address);
    TextView deviceName = (TextView) gorunum.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
    deviceName.setText(Dvc.name);
    return gorunum;
}
```

}

Any idea ?

Comment: Post the error message you get when it crash

Comment: Now it doesn't crash, it simply doesn't enter the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

This strings is wrong and crash you code:
 `if(device.getName().equals(null))` and the `if(device.getAddress().equals(null))`
because if device is null it's don't understand .getName() and .getAddress() methods, also if the method .getName() return null it means that null.equals(null), but in this case null don't know method .equals();, so make sense to change your strings to:
`if(device != null && ("null").equals(""+device.getName()))` and to 
`if(device != null && ("null").equals(""+device.getAddress()))`
Obviously you need to handle the situation if the device == null before other checks.

Comment: Actually there was no if statement at first. It was still crashing and then I put these if statements with 'null' in case it works. I think there is something else which is wrong with my code.

Comment: Looks like that this strings in the wrong place: `deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(FoundDevicesActivity.this, foundedDevicesList);
            foundedDevicesListView.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);`  And they create many adapters exept one.

Comment: When I put it, after registerReceiver, again it crashes.

Comment: Now check the import strings. You create the `Device` class but you use the `android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass.Device` class to. I think that make sense to rename you custom class to MyDevice and then check import strings.